# Distinguish [gflags] already?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-wiki

I see two kind of [[gflags] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gflags) coming up

- GFlags as [debugging settings under Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- gflags, a [command line parameter library](https://code.google.com/p/gflags/)

There are 32 questions in total only, so I wonder whether it's time to edit the tag wiki and possibly split into two unique tags.